# Serialize/de-serialize Boost.Geometry rtree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization, r-tree, boost-geometry

Short version: is there any stable/reliable way to serialize/de-serialize a Boost.Geometry rtree ?

Longer version: The rtree implementation in Boost.Geometry has experimental support for serialization/de-serialization, but the support is unstable, it sometimes throws exceptions during de-serialization. I don't even know whether it corrupts the tree data silently.

I have implemented a simple but very slow hack: serialize all the tree nodes (instead of the tree as a whole), and rebuild the tree during de-serialization. I want something faster.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? It still does not provide stable support for serialization in `1.7.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the packing-constructor which affords bulk-loading.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/introduction.html

  > Additionally there are also algorithms creating R-tree containing some, number of objects. This technique is called bulk loading and is done by use of packing algorithm [5] [6]. This method is faster and results in R-trees with better internal structure. This means that the query performance is increased.

  As you can see, you can expect to get best query performance from the packing algorithm anyways: [image]

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/rtree_iterator__iterator_.html
 *

```
namespace  bgi  =  boost::geometry::index; 
typedef  std::pair<Box,  int>  Value; 
typedef  bgi::rtree<  Value,  bgi::linear<32>  >  RTree; 

std::vector<Value>  values; 
/*fill the values container*/ 

RTree  rt; 
rt.insert(values.begin(),  values.end());
```

If your iterators are input iterators you can avoid having a temporary copy at all (`values` container doesn't need to be a container).

Comment: I don't quite understand the boost introduction page. Since packing is a creation algorithm, and linear/quadratic/rstar are balancing algorithms, I should get 6 different r-trees, but the diagrams only show 4 trees. Does that mean packing can only be implemented on linearly balanced trees ?

Comment: There is only one packing algorithm implemented at the moment. So if you create the R-tree using packing algorithm always the same structure is created no matter which balancing algorithm was picked. But when you add or remove a value to/from this R-tree then choosen balancing algorithm is used.

Comment: Hi there. I attempted this solution and I didn't get any improvement on runtime. I am using boost::geometry::model::d2 to build the boxes, may this be the issue?