# boost r-tree packing algorithm during insertion

Tags: c++, performance, boost, r-tree

The question is about the `boost::geometry::index::rtree`:

I know that the constructor: `rtree(Iterator, Iterator)` will create the tree using the packing algorithm, as stated in the documentation. I'm wondering whether the insertion which accepts the iterators: `insert(Iterator, Iterator)` will also use the packing algorithm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packing algorithm is used if the R-tree is created from items given to the constructor. The balancing algorithm is used during splitting of nodes i.e. on insert() and remove().

So the answer is no. During insertion the packing algorithm is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm assuming that the packing algorithm is only used during the creation.

Comment by Adam Wulkiewicz, one of the boost::geometry developers:

"There is only one packing algorithm implemented at the moment. So if you create the R-tree using packing algorithm always the same structure is created no matter which balancing algorithm was picked. But when you add or remove a value to/from this R-tree then choosen balancing algorithm is used"

Source: [Serialize/de-serialize Boost.Geometry rtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256361/serialize-de-serialize-boost-geometry-rtree)

Comment: Yup. I was going to find that info, but you found it already

Comment: If the same initial rtree can be used for all balancing algorithms, can we modify the balancing algorithm during execution?